# React Native 0.56: bundle doesn't produce .meta file - Is it still needed?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

Seems that the `jsbundle.meta` is no longer produced when running a build in 0.56 (though `main.jsbundle` is fine).

Is it needed? What does it do? There is zero documentation on this file.

My build command:

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle- 
output ios/files/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/files/
```

I ran the app with a Release scheme and it failed due to the meta file being declared in XCode "Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources." Removing it there also solved the issue when jsbundle.meta was not present, but I'm still unsure about removing it.

Any thoughts/experience appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was [removed from metro](https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/c35f1a2c013d9a4626321aa134d1b406e0ff8efa) a while back. No mention in the release notes about it though. I think there's no need to worry about it.